# Development Cordova App with Red5pro live stream

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, red5

I'm trying to understand Cordova & Red5pro for streaming mobile. I need to create an application that live streams phone to phone.

I have so many questions and from bottom to top.

Can anybody help me with that?